# HttpParty::Response and try(:parsed_response) weird behavior

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activesupport, httparty

I've tried to use ActiveSupport's (2.3-stable) try() on an instance of HttpParty::Response. I've got a pretty strange behavior:

```
> ro.parsed_response
{"error"=>"RecordInvalid", "description"=>"Record validation errors", "details"=>{"email"=>     [{"description"=>"Email: foo@bar.com is already taken by another user"}]}}

> ro.try(:parsed_response)
NoMethodError Exception: undefined method `parsed_response' for #<Hash:0x11397d5d8>
```

In the first example, I send the parsed_response message to ro by using the dot notation. It works fine. In the second one, I try to call it using ActiveSupport's try(), and it (surprisingly) raises the NoMethodError exception.

Shouldn't try() have returned nil in this case? And why doesn't it find the "parsed_response" method, if I can call it using the dot notation, as seen in the first example?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi ted, yes I'm on Ruby 1.8.7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have no idea how, but seems like `ro` object was "transfered" into a hash that has been sent a  `parsed_response` method.
In Rails 2.3@ruby 1.8 [undefined method for object raises an exception](http://apidock.com/rails/Object/try#798-Doesn-t-return-nil-if-the-object-you-try-from-isn-t-nil-).

Besides, docs stay only for calling try on *nil* object and nothing about the object that doesn't have a specific method:

> Unlike that method however, a NoMethodError exception will not be
>   raised and nil will be returned instead, if the receiving object is a
>   nil object or NilClass.

Comment: Yeah, looks like it. Ruby's flexibility sometimes can shoot back at you. Thank you for the reply.